# I found one link but i don't know what is that

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, security

In my website I check security scan and I found one link but I don't know where is that link

I search my whole website pages but don't find anything

```
/index.php
/                          <-- this link
/artists.php
/byartwork.php
/bytattoo.php
/byartist.php
/contactus.php
/appointment.php
/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection
```

I want to remove this link. Please tell me where I can find this and what it is.

Comment: A link to `/` means the "root directory". It will normally default to `index.php`. So, there is no need to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

The / means that is the website's root directory. It basically means that is the home page of your website. For example, the moment you go to https://www.google.com you will be greeted by the home page.

Comment: but how to hide that. That / make slow my website

Comment: @Krishna I think you can use .htaccess for that. The / won't slow your website :)